# What am I doing wrong here (trying to print employee class)

Tags: python, class

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/cenni/OneDrive/Desktop/Computer science work and notes/Chapter 11 #1.py", line 20, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/cenni/OneDrive/Desktop/Computer science work and notes/Chapter 11 #1.py", line 18, in main
    print('Your name is ' + self.name(), + ' your employee number is ' + self.number(), + 'your shift number is ', + self.Snumber(), + ' your pay is ', + self.pay(), ' an hour.')
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

```
 class Employee:
     def __init__(self, name, number, Snumber, Pay):
         self.name = name
         self.number = number
         
 
     def ProductionWorker(self, Snumber, pay):
         self.Snumber = Snumber
         self.pay = pay
 
 def main():
     employee_name = input("Please enter your name: ")
     employee_number = input("Please enter your employee number: ")
     employee_Snumber = input("Please enter your shift number: ")
     employee_pay = input("Please enter your hourly wage: ")
     employee_info = Employee(employee_name, employee_number, employee_Snumber, employee_pay)
 
     print('Your name is ' + self.name(), + ' your employee number is ' + self.number(), + 'your shift number is ', + self.Snumber(), + ' your pay is ', + self.pay(), ' an hour.')
 
 main()
```

I am unsure of how to fix this issue. i am trying to design a program that prints all of the classes and subclasses values.

Comment: You don't have an instance of `Employee` named `self`; you have one named `employee_info`. `self` is just the parameter named used by `Employee` methods.

Comment: You never call the `ProductionWorker()` method that assigns `Snumber` and `pay`.

Comment: There are no subclasses here.

Comment: Is `ProductionWorker` supposed to be a subclass of `Employee`? That seems more logical.

Comment: Yes, production worker is supposed to be a subclass

Comment: Please read the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) help page. I think your title could be improved.

Answer (score 1):

`self` is a local variable in the class methods. Outside the methods, the variable that contains the employee is `employee_info`, so use that in the `print()` call.

`__init__()` needs to call `self.productionWorker()` to set `self.Snumber` and `self.pay`.

You shouldn't have `()` after `employee_info.name`, in the `print()` call. These are data attributes, not methods, so you don't call them.

```
class Employee:
     def __init__(self, name, number, Snumber, Pay):
         self.name = name
         self.number = number
         self.productionWorker(Snumber, Pay)
 
     def ProductionWorker(self, Snumber, pay):
         self.Snumber = Snumber
         self.pay = pay
 
 def main():
     employee_name = input("Please enter your name: ")
     employee_number = input("Please enter your employee number: ")
     employee_Snumber = input("Please enter your shift number: ")
     employee_pay = input("Please enter your hourly wage: ")
     employee_info = Employee(employee_name, employee_number, employee_Snumber, employee_pay)
 
     print('Your name is ' + employee_info.name, + ' your employee number is ' + employee_info.number, + 'your shift number is ', + employee_info.Snumber, + ' your pay is ', + employee_info.pay, ' an hour.')
 
main()
```

Comment: Thankyou so much for the help you have no clue how much it means to me!

Comment: any reason why im getting the error "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\cenni\OneDrive\Desktop\Computer science work and notes\Chapter 11 #1.py", line 20, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\cenni\OneDrive\Desktop\Computer science work and notes\Chapter 11 #1.py", line 18, in main
    print('Your name is ' + employee_info.name(), + ' your employee number is ' + employee_info.number(), + 'your shift number is ', + employee_info.Snumber(), + ' your pay is ', + employee_info.pay(), ' an hour.')
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable"

Comment: I was trying the code you gave me

Comment: That came from the code you gave me, I didn't notice that error. `name` is an attribute, not a method, it doesn't need `()` after it.

Comment: hey sorry for bothering you again. (i made the changes you suggested) and im getting this error (Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Chris/Desktop/Computer science notes/Chap 11 #1.py", line 20, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/Chris/Desktop/Computer science notes/Chap 11 #1.py", line 18, in main
    print('Your name is ' + employee_info.name, + ' your employee number is ' + employee_info.number, + 'your shift number is ', + employee_info.Snumber, + ' your pay is ', + employee_info.pay, ' an hour.')
TypeError: bad operand type for unary +: 'str')

Comment: Don't use `,` before `+`.

Comment: It seems like you need to refresh your knowledge of python basics, then work up to OOP.

Comment: I love you sir thankyou for all that you have done to help